# Activity Return Transitions - Shared Elements - Killed Activity

Tags: android, animation, android-support-library, android-design-library

Library used:  appcompat-v7:22.2.1,design:22.2.1

Theme used:

Devices/Android versions reproduced on: Nexus 6

Issue: Return activity quickly redraws/appears then fades in with desired behaviour, only with `"Don't keep activities alive"`.

I am wondering if this is a bug or expected behaviour.  I have a very simple setup.  Activity A contains a toolbar wrapped in an `AppbarLayout` and `CoorindinatorLayout`. The toolbar contains a `Cardview` and a `TextView`. Upon click of the `TextView`, Activity A launches Activity B.  I am using shared elements and passing them through as Option's via `ActivityCompat.StartActivity(bundle, options);`

My shared elements work perfectly, even after device rotation. After reading about how I can `PostPoneEnterTransition` and combo it up with `PreDrawListeners` I am able to successfully achieve the desired transition even after rotation. My actual activity contains a `Viewpager` / `TabLayout` and 2+ fragments but for simplicity sake, I've stripped it back in the video as well as to see if something else was causing this issue.

While dealing with rotation and postponing of the enter transition back to Activity A, I decided to open developer options and check `"Don't keep activities alive"`.  The [video](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=1822660000000&name=device-2015-08-07-194141.mp4&token=ABZ6GAeuAwy112bSrI5Rc1HlOWGQ9XsNSw%3A1438999788611&id=182266&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAdNizGB7vvZhPyVwhapTg5OUn-0fg%3A1438999788611) depicts the app running with that option enabled. If you look closely, you can see upon return to Activity A, it is completely drawn and hidden very quickly and then the fade in occurs as well as the shared element transition.

I've also excluded the navigation bar and status bar in the animations so that I don't see those flicker (redraw redundantly).

My questions are:

1. Is this a bug, or am I missing a step in order to prevent this.
2. Why would the app/transitions behave differently with `"Don't keep activities alive"` vs a plain old device rotation (destroy/recreate).
3. I've noticed by playing around with some google apps, this behaviour does not occur, or at least that I could find. Is there a way to concretely check if the activity I am returning too is "completely destroyed" so I can cancel the animation? Or do something different?

I can include specifics and code samples if required but my setup is very simple, and reflects a bunch of boilerplate examples from the Android documentation / Stack-overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I meant to respond to this earlier. What I ended up doing was recreating the example in a completely fresh project following code samples and tutorials as best I could. First making it work with a single image view, and then of course adding my custom layout which was a floating search bar. Everything worked as expected. I went back and reviewed my actual project source (which was littered with different attempts and commented out code while trying to debug this issue) and cleaned it up. I can't say for sure, but I believe it came down to two possible issues:

"Unless you do something unusual..." - Most likely I "was" doing something unusual by the time I created this issue do to my debugging efforts and lack of full comprehension of the shared elements transition framework and lifecycle.

I think what was happening was the shared element transition was failing do to views not being mapped properly. I was excluding the statusBarBackground inside a transition defined in XML.  My statusBarBackground was set to transparent so that I had the nice overlay effect for an expanded drawer layout. I found out that while trying to add the statusbarbackground as a shared element via code, the view was actually null resulting in a crash (NPE). As well as I had set a background color (instead of transparent) to my drawer layout.  I can't say for sure, but a combination of these mistakes lead to the strange behaviour.

To conclude, I would say that this issue should be closed and everything is working as intended. It would be nice to get a little more insight on handling a transparent status bar as a shared element.

1. Is this a bug, or am I missing a step in order to prevent this?

   `No. Everything is working as intended.`
2. Why would the app/transitions behave differently with "Don't keep activities alive" vs a plain old device rotation (destroy/recreate)?

   `It doesn't. When everything is setup proper and your timing and mapping of shared elements is correct, "Don't keep activities alive" is a concrete way to test your transitions against configuration changes.`
3. I've noticed by playing around with some google apps, this behaviour does not occur, or at least that I could find. Is there a way to concretely check if the activity I am returning too is "completely destroyed" so I can cancel the animation? Or do something different?

   `This is because the Google dev's did it right :)`

For anyone struggling with shared elements, here is a bit of advice.

1. Start small. Use a single view first and confirm you are getting the correct behaviour in all circumstances, even after rotation and config changes, then you can add complexity.
2. Use SharedElementCallback to debug your transitions. You can check which views are mapped, which view failed etc.

Comment: Could you share some code showing how you handled the rotation?